# I want to request a link, but there is "Traceback (most recent call last)"

Tags: python, python-requests

When I try to request a link, I got an error.
How can I fix the problem?
Thank you

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 368, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='61.143.53.130', port=4432): Max retries exceeded with url: /zhpubweb/SaleMsg.aspx?recnumgather=201913858407 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    res = requests.get('https://61.143.53.130:4432/zhpubweb/SaleMsg.aspx?recnumgather=201913858407')
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='61.143.53.130', port=4432): Max retries exceeded with url: /zhpubweb/SaleMsg.aspx?recnumgather=201913858407 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))
>>> res = requests.get('https://61.143.53.130:4432/zhpubweb/SaleMsg.aspx?recnumgather=201913858407')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 368, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='61.143.53.130', port=4432): Max retries exceeded with url: /zhpubweb/SaleMsg.aspx?recnumgather=201913858407 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    res = requests.get('https://61.143.53.130:4432/zhpubweb/SaleMsg.aspx?recnumgather=201913858407')
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yu Chen Su\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='61.143.53.130', port=4432): Max retries exceeded with url: /zhpubweb/SaleMsg.aspx?recnumgather=201913858407 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))
>>>
```

Comment: You can set in your request verify=False. I don't recomend it (only for development). If you upload your code instead of that traceback we may try to help. **res = requests.get('https://61.143.53.130:4432/zhpubweb/SaleMsg.aspx?recnumgather=201913858407',verify=False)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Python problem, the url your are requesting with is configured incorrectly. You can ignore any certificate errors with for instance :

```
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS, verify=False)
```